# Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) more than one line

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have implemented the FCM in my app. When i push a message to my App, i can see, that it only displays one line, and the message is then shorten with "...". Is there a possiblity to send a longer message (for example two or three lines=, that can be displayed?

Would be great, if you can give me a hint.

Thanks very much

Comment: How do you push? What displays the message?

Comment: i push through the firebase console and it is displayed by the app, through the FCM implentation of the tutorial.

Comment: in that case the notification is generated by firebase and you cannot change its appearance

Comment: oh, thats sad. so there is no possiblity to push messages by FCM that are longer than one line?

Comment: Sure there are, but you have to do it without the firebase console. Like set up a server

Comment: But whats the difference on the "sending" site, i thought it is the client, that cant display the message correctly, if the app is in background?

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue and has been fixed in the latest version of Google Play services SDK v9.4.0. In this version Big Style notification was used so notifications that have messages longer than the screen width can be expanded to show full text.